# bash: command works in terminal, not in script

Tags: linux, bash, newline

I am doing

```
a="$(openssl x509 -in /path/to/pemfile.pem -text -noout)";
echo ${a} |grep -a1 -b2 Signature
```

which works quite well if i put this line into terminal

However, if i put the very same line in a file `executeme.sh`, `chmod +x executeme.sh`, `./executeme.sh`

I seems does not create the linebreaks in the variable, resulting grep to receive just one line. output is as follows on the terminal:

```
20- Version: 3 (0x2)
38- Serial Number: 32 (0x27)
64: Signature Algorithm: md5WithRSAEncryption
107- Issuer: C=EN, ST=a, L=b, O=c, OU=d, CN=e
244- Validity
------
[...]
```

The script outputs the entire certificate , as if i would only do `a="$(openssl ...)"; echo ${a}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do

```
echo "${a}" |grep -a1 -b2 Signature #mind the double quotes
```

**Why doublequotes?**

See [[ this ]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/754408/1620779) answer + [[ this ]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/754506/1620779) answer.

Comment: @Joel : Thanks for accepting, Do have a look at the links, especially the second one.

Comment: I understand, that it is working. `echo` seems to output as shot as possible - right? Apperently, I can avoid it, forcing the specified String (${a}) to be seen as a whole string.

Comment: @Joel : Kinda. Double quotes prevents squeezing of space characters which include whitespace, tabs and linefeeds and so.