# How to fill a case statement baised on the outcome of a find with bash?

Tags: bash, find

How to fill a case statement in a bash script, baised on the directories in a folder.
So I have the following folder /opt/servers/ in this folder I have the following directories:
server1
server2
server3

Each of these directories equals a servername within Websphere Liberty.

How can I put those in a case statement?

I also want to use this script on multiple servers, and the serversnames are not the same, so I don't want to put the names of the servers hardcoded in the script. Because if an extra server will be added or removed I need to edit the script again an put that servername in there.

If I use the following, I get all the directories:

```
find /opt/servers/ -type d -name *server* | sort | awk -F'/' '{print $(NF-0)}'
```

But if I put the find in a variable and the echo it again, it print all the servers on one line:

```
SERVERS=`find /opt/wlp/ -type d -name *server*| sort | awk -F'/' '{print $(NF-0)}'`
echo $SERVERS
server1 server2 server3
```

How can I solve this?
The goal is, that when a server is selected I get a new menu, where I can stop or start the server.
So the script will do something like:

```
Hello please select one of the servers below:
1) server1
2) server2
3) server3

You have selected: server1
What do you want to do with this server?
1) stop
2) start

You have selected: stop
Are you sure?
1) Yes
2) No

You have selected: Yes
server1 will be stopped.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Losing newline after assigning grep result to a shell variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754395/losing-newline-after-assigning-grep-result-to-a-shell-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fill a bash array with the servers dirpaths and then use it to implement your logic:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

servers=( /opt/servers/*server* )

echo "Hello please select one of the servers below:"
select server in "${servers[@]##*/}"
do
    [[ $server ]] || continue
    echo "You have selected: $server"
    break
done

echo "What do you want to do with this server?"
select action in stop start
do
    [[ $action ]] || continue
    echo "You have selected: $action"
    break
done

# etc...
```

Comment: I get an error when I try to use that:  
`./script.sh: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token <'
./script.sh: line 6: mapfile -t -d '' servers < <(printf '%s\0' /opt/wlp/*servers*)'`

Comment: @fabje Make sure to add the shebang `#!/bin/bash` as the first line of the script. Updated my answer

Comment: `line 2: mapfile: -d: invalid option` I also see that we have bash 4.2.46 installed, and I can't update that, and seems like I need 4.3.

Comment: Edited the answer to show you the way