# What is the exact meaning of IFS=$'\n'?

Tags: bash, shell, variables, environment-variables, ifs

If the following example, which sets the `IFS` environment variable to a line feed character...

```
IFS=$'\n'
```

- What does the **dollar sign** mean
  **exactly**?
- What does it do in this specific
  case?
- Where can I read more on this specific usage (Google doesn't allow special characters in searches and I don't know what to look for otherwise)?

I know what the `IFS` environment variable is, and what the `\n` character is (line feed), but why not just use the following form: 
`IFS="\n"` (which does not work)?

For example, if I want to loop through every line of a file and want to use a for loop, I could do this:

```
for line in (< /path/to/file); do
    echo "Line: $line"
done
```

However, this won't work right unless `IFS` is set to a line feed character. To get it to work, I'd have to do this:

```
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
for line in (< /path/to/file); do
    echo "Line: $line"
done
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

**Note:** I don't need another way for doing the same thing, I know many other already... I'm only curious about that `$'\n'` and wondered if anyone could give me an explanation on it.

Answer (score 175, accepted):

Normally `bash` doesn't interpret escape sequences in string literals. So if you write `\n` or `"\n"` or `'\n'`, that's not a linebreak - it's the letter `n` (in the first case) or a backslash followed by the letter `n` (in the other two cases).

`$'somestring'` is a **syntax for string literals with escape sequences**. So unlike `'\n'`, `$'\n'` actually is a linebreak.

Comment: Not exactly so -- `\n` is just an (escaped) letter n. You are right that `'\n'` and `"\n"` are backlash followed by n.

Comment: Note that `$'\n'` is bash specific -- it won't work in a POSIX shell (`/bin/sh`).  To get the same effect in a POSIX-compliant manner, you can type `IFS='`, then hit return to type an actual newline character, then type the closing `'`

Comment: `IFS=$(echo -e '\n')` should also do it in a POSIX-compatible way.

Comment: @Vineet - it gave me pause to dispute an upvoted comment.  While this *is* Posix-correct, it doesn't work - The command substitution operators in bash remove all trailing newline characters.  See [this for more detail](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17732/where-has-the-trailing-newline-char-gone-from-my-command-substitution).

Comment: Make sure that the script starts with "!/bin/bash" and not "!/bin/sh". Not relevant but may be a pitfall.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma I think it's not even POSIX: `-e` is not defined, and `\n` without `-e` works as an XSI extension: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html#tag_20_37 . `printf '\n'` rocks ;)

Comment: A rather unexpected side effect of using `IFS='\n'` (without the dollar sign) is that your user name gets truncated if it has an `n` in it (This bug is how I got to this thread). `echo $USER` yields `brade` instead of `braden` in my case.

Comment: @Richard Hansen: It is not working in my bash. Has this changed in newer versions of bash? I am using 4.2.46(2)-release

Comment: Here is an actual POSIX solution: `nl="$(printf '\nx')"; nl="${nl%x}"; IFS="$nl"`. By printing an extra character with our newline, the newline isn't lost under command substitution. Then we just use parameter expansion to remove the extra character.

Answer (score 27):

Just to give the construct its **official name**: strings of the form `$'...'` are called **[ANSI C-quoted strings](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting)**.

That is, as in [ANSI] C strings, **backlash escape sequences** are recognized and **expanded to their literal equivalent** (see below for the complete list of supported escape sequences).

***After* this expansion, `$'...'` strings behave the same way as `'...'` strings** - i.e., they're treated as ***literals* NOT subject to any [further] shell expansions**.

For instance, `$'\n'` expands to a literal newline character - which is something a regular bash string literal (whether `'...'` or `"..."`) cannot do.<sup>[1]</sup>

Another interesting feature is that **ANSI C-quoted strings can escape `'` (single quotes) as `\'`**, which, `'...'` (regular single-quoted strings) cannot:

```
echo $'Honey, I\'m home' # OK; this cannot be done with '...'
```

**List of supported escape sequences**:

> Backslash escape sequences, if present, are decoded as follows:
>
> \a
>   alert (bell)
>
> \b
>   backspace
>
> \e
>   \E
>   an escape character (not ANSI C)
>
> \f
>   form feed
>
> \n
>   newline
>
> \r
>   carriage return
>
> \t
>   horizontal tab
>
> \v
>   vertical tab
>
> \
>   backslash
>
> \'
>   single quote
>
> \"
>   double quote
>
> \nnn
>   the eight-bit character whose value is the octal value nnn (one to three digits)
>
> \xHH
>   the eight-bit character whose value is the hexadecimal value HH (one or two hex digits)
>
> \uHHHH
>   the Unicode (ISO/IEC 10646) character whose value is the hexadecimal value HHHH (one to four hex digits)
>
> \UHHHHHHHH
>   the Unicode (ISO/IEC 10646) character whose value is the hexadecimal value HHHHHHHH (one to eight hex digits)
>
> \cx
>   a control-x character
>
> The expanded result is single-quoted, as if the dollar sign had not been present.

---

<sup>[1] You can, however, embed *actual* newlines in '...' and "..." strings; i.e., you can define strings that span multiple lines.</sup>

Answer (score 16):

From http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/bash_guide_for_beginners/sect_03_03.html:

> Words in the form "$'STRING'" are
>   treated in a special way. The word
>   expands to a string, with
>   backslash-escaped characters replaced
>   as specified by the ANSI-C standard.
>   Backslash escape sequences can be
>   found in the Bash documentation.found

I guess it's forcing the script to escape the line feed to the proper ANSI-C standard.

Answer (score 9):

Re recovering the default IFS- this `OLDIFS=$IFS` is not necessary. Run new IFS in subshell to avoid overriding the default IFS:

```
ar=(123 321); ( IFS=$'\n'; echo ${ar[*]} )
```

Besides I don't really believe you recover the old IFS fully. You should double quote it to avoid line breaking such as `OLDIFS="$IFS"`.

Comment: this is a really useful technique. i just used it for a cleaner shell join op: `args=$(IFS='&'; echo "$*")`. restoring `IFS` to `$' \t\n'` in a Bourne shell friendly manner is no mean feat.

Comment: Re `Besides I don't really believe you recover the old IFS fully`: word splitting is _not_ performed on the RHS of variable assignments (but quote removal is), so `OLDIFS=$IFS` and `OLDIFS="$IFS"` behave the same way.

Answer (score 3):

ANSI C-quoted strings is a key point. Thanks to @mklement0 .

You can test ANSI C-quoted strings with command od.

```
echo -n $'\n' | od -c
echo -n '\n' | od -c
echo -n $"\n" | od -c
echo -n "\n" | od -c
```

Outputs:

```
0000000  \n  
0000001

0000000   \   n   
0000002

0000000   \   n   
0000002

0000000   \   n   
0000002
```

You can know the meaning clearly by the outputs.

Answer (score 2):

### Question:

What is the exact meaning of `IFS=$'\n'`?

### Simple Answer:

Hey Bash! set the **Internal Field Separator (IFS)** to **New Line**

---

### What is `IFS` ?

`IFS` is the character, Bash uses as word/item boundaries when processing character strings.

It is set to whitespace characters of *space*, *tab*, and *newline*, **by default**.

### Example 1:

Use default value for `IFS`

```
string="first second:third forth:fifth"

for item in $string; do
    echo "$item"
done
```

**Output:**

```
first
second:third
forth:fifth
```

### Example 2:

Set `IFS` to `:`

```
# Set the IFS to collon (:) character
IFS=:

string="first second:third forth:fifth"

for item in $string; do
    echo "$item"
done
```

**Output:**

```
first second  
third forth  
fifth
```

Answer (score -9):

It's like retrieving the value from a variable:

```
VAR='test'
echo VAR
echo $VAR
```

are different, so the dollar sign basically evaluates the content.

Comment: This has nothing to do with variables. `$'FOO'` (unlike `$FOO` which this was question was not about) is a string literal. If you execute `echo $'VAR'`, you'll see that it prints the string `VAR`, not `test`.