# Iteration over strings contain white spaces

Tags: bash

I'm doing a simple iteration over a remote text file content, but get stuck in splitting file names as they have spaces inside.

```
#!/bin/bash
for u in $(curl http://XXXXXX.com/urls.txt)
do
    wget "${u%|*}" -O "${u#*|}" -P ./Directory/
done
```

Text file contains below strings per line:

```
https://OOOOOOOO.com?url1|My file with spaces in name.mp4
https://OOOOOOOO.com?url2|How to escape spaces?.mp4
https://OOOOOOOO.com?url3|Mixed up.mp4
https://OOOOOOOO.com?url4|Asking StackOverFlow!.mp4
```

I looked at many similar issues already, made many approaches but all results the same thing.

When I do a `echo ${u#*|}` alone, I have the output:

```
My
file
with
spaces
in
name.mp4
Mixed
up.mp4
.
.
.
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `while-read` loop would be simpler here:

```
curl http://XXXXXX.com/urls.txt |
while IFS='|' read -r url filename; do
    wget "${url}" -O "${filename}" -P ./Directory/
done
```

Answer (score 1):

use `Input Field Separator (IFS)`

> This variable determines how Bash recognizes fields, or word
>   boundaries, when it interprets character strings.
>   [LINK](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html)

e.g:

```
IFS=$'\n'
for u in $(cat file)
do
   echo ${u#*|}
done
```

OUTPUT:

```
My file with spaces in name.mp4
How to escape spaces?.mp4
Mixed up.mp4
Asking StackOverFlow!.mp4
```

Comment: Thanks! I used `IFS` for newlines before, but splitting was done with `read` and not these shell globs! Would you mind to say what's wrong with mine? and what's the `$` after `IFS=`?

Comment: @revo : read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128235/bash-shell-scripting-what-is-the-exact-meaning-of-ifs-n

Comment: Don't mess with IFS on the read. Just do `while read -d '|' url fname; do whatever; done <$filename` That will save the first part in `url` and the second in `fname`. The just quote `"$fname"` when you use it.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Would you add your comment as an answer?

Comment: Be glad to, but Glen already posted the equivalent. More than happy to let him have the credit :)