# Generating bash script arrays with elements containing spaces from commands

Tags: bash

I have a script that logs in to a remote host to pull a directory listing to later present options to the user. It was all working perfectly, until some of the directories started having spaces in them. I have tried several syntaxes and googled the life out of this and I am now at the end of my tether. The original command was this:

```
SERVERDIRS=($(sshpass -p $PASS ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no $USER@$SERVER ls -l --time-style="long-iso" $FROMFOLDER | egrep '^d' | awk '{print $8}'))
```

I first off changed this code to be able to read the spaces like this:

```
SERVERDIRS=($(sshpass -p $PASS ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no $USER@$SERVER ls -l --time-style="long-iso" $FROMFOLDER | egrep '^d' | cut -d' ' -f8-))
```

However This resulted in each word being recognised as a variable. I have tried many ways to try to solve this, two of which were:

```
SERVERDIRS=($(sshpass -p $PASS ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no $USER@$SERVER ls -d $FROMFOLDER*  |rev| cut -d'/' -f1|rev|sed s/^/\"/g|sed s/$/\"/g))
SERVERDIRS=($(sshpass -p $PASS ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no $USER@$SERVER ls -d $FROMFOLDER*  |rev| cut -d'/' -f1|rev|sed 's/ /\\ /g'))
SERVERDIRS=(`sshpass -p $PASS ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no $USER@$SERVER ls -d $FROMFOLDER*  |rev| cut -d'/' -f1|rev|sed 's/ /\\ /g'`)
```

How can I resolve these directories in to separate elements correctly?

Comment: I'm not sure if it will work but you could try changing $IFS to something other than space so that the spaces don't cause the script to parse the space separated string as separate attibutes? [this may help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128235/bash-shell-scripting-what-is-the-exact-meaning-of-ifs-n)

Comment: I would start by the most obvious thing, double quoting your variables to prevent the whitespace problems. "$FROMFOLDER" should do the trick i guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to read one array value per line instead of space-separated, then `$()` syntax won't help. Try [`readarray`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11395181/1426891) (Bash 4):

```
readarray SERVERDIRS < <(sshpass -p $PASS ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no $USER@$SERVER ls -l --time-style="long-iso" $FROMFOLDER | egrep '^d' | cut -d' ' -f8-)
```

or [assign `IFS` and `read` with `-d`, `-r`, and `-a` set](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11395181/1426891):

```
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a SERVERDIRS < <(sshpass -p $PASS ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no $USER@$SERVER ls -l --time-style="long-iso" $FROMFOLDER | egrep '^d' | cut -d' ' -f8-)
```

or, really, any other answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11393817/1426891).

If you're unfamiliar with `<()` syntax, it's known as [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) and will allow your variable to be set in  your current environment rather than the instantly-discarded subshell that a pipe would create.

Bear in mind that this process is a little dangerous; filenames can also contain newlines, so it's usually much preferred to [use `find ... -print0`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1116992/1426891).

Comment: The readarray option did not work but I eventually got it to work by reassigning IFS to new line (and putting back to normal after, of course). Seems a bit hacky, but gets the job done. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

If you only need to list directories, try this

```
ls -d /usr/local/src/*/
```

or

```
ls -d /path/to/your/directory/*/
```

You can then loop through all directories

```
#!/bin/bash

aa=`ls -d /usr/local/src/*/`

for dir in "${aa}[@]"
do
  echo "$dir"
done
```

This works if dir names contain spaces.