# Quoting in sh bash ... ("") ($'') ('')

Tags: bash, shell, quoting

I hopefully would like to say I understand quotings used in BASH and their difference , `" "`, `' '`, `$' '`.

I saw many shell scripts containing

```
IFS=$'\n'
```

but NO

```
IFS="\n"
```

It looks at least to me that there is no difference.
and in my environment both work correctly (for my understanding), 
What difference is here? Is it just a custom?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bash/shell scripting: What is the exact meaning of IFS=$'\n'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128235/bash-shell-scripting-what-is-the-exact-meaning-of-ifs-n)

Comment: Note that [ANSI C Quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) is different again from single quoting and double quoting and back-quoting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They aren't the same.

`IFS=$'\n'` sets the value of `IFS` to a literal newline.

`IFS="\n"` sets the value of `IFS` to the string `\n`.

See?

```
$ IFS=$'\n'
$ declare -p IFS
declare -- IFS="
"
$ IFS="\n"
$ declare -p IFS
declare -- IFS="\\n"

$ IFS="\n" read a b c <<<$'anbncndn'
$ declare -p a b c
declare -- a="a"
declare -- b="b"
declare -- c="cndn"
$ IFS=$'\n' read a b c <<<$'anbncndn'
$ declare -p a b c
declare -- a="anbncndn"
declare -- b=""
declare -- c=""
```

Comment: I saw the difference!
I am not sure difference caused from it.. but I comprehend.
(I mean 'in practical use') But I may remember what you taught me someday when I face something

Thank you very much.