# Capture multiline output as array in bash not working

Tags: bash

i have this script

```
#!/bin/bash
MVAR=($(su - git -C "sftp user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx << EOF
pwd
EOF
" ))
echo ${MVAR[2]}
```

the output look like this
`Connected to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.
Remote`

how can i modify script to have

`Connected to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.
Remote working directory:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it splits on spaces due to [IFS (Internal Field Separator)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26784/understanding-ifs). Try defining `IFS` to [newlines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128235/bash-shell-scripting-what-is-the-exact-meaning-of-ifs-n):

```
$ IFS=$'\n' MVAR=($(su - git -C "sftp user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx << EOF
pwd
EOF
" ))
```

I could make your command work on my machine. I used this one to test locally and get the remote pwd:

```
$ IFS=$'\n' MVAR=($(sftp -b <(echo pwd) localhost))
$ echo ${abc[1]}
sftp> pwd
$ echo ${abc[2]}                                   
Remote working directory: /home/cbliard
```