# Regex breakdown for LD_PATH extraction

Tags: regex

I previously used an answer from [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922949/how-to-print-the-ldlinker-search-path) that shows how to get a list of the linker paths on a system, `ldconfig -v 2>/dev/null | grep -v ^$'\t'`.

What I don't get is how the regex makes sense. The `^$` should match empty lines, so how does the trailing `'\t'` even get checked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first assumption is off:

- The `^` is interpreted as beginning-of-line.
- The `$` is treated as part of a shell expansion that forms `$'\t'`. This is to escape a character literal in the shell. [The same approach is used when changing the internal field separator (IFS).](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128235/what-is-the-exact-meaning-of-ifs-n)

In short, the regex evaluates to "exclude lines that begin with hard-tabs".