# Iterate through folder files in Ubuntu 16

Tags: bash, shell, centos, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to iterate through some files in a specific folder to do a specific operation in each of them (using Neuroimaging tool FSL).

When I do

```
$ find /home/Desktop/MSc/ImagensMRI/T1/t1inciais/t1alzheimer/
```

It returns a list of all the files in that folder

So I did

```
$  for i in 'find /home/Desktop/MSc/ImagensMRI/T1/t1inciais/t1alzheimer/';do /usr/share/fsl/5.0/bin/bet $i ${i}_brain -f 0.4 -g 0;done
```

But the outcome of that is

```
Error: input image find not valid
```

I was able to do this in CentOS 7, so I'd guess that could be the root of the problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a *shell  glob* :

```
$ for i in /home/Desktop/MSc/ImagensMRI/T1/t1inciais/t1alzheimer/*; do 
    bet "$i" "${i}_brain" -f 0.4 -g 0
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-exec` option to `find`:

```
find /home/Desktop/MSc/ImagensMRI/T1/t1inciais/t1alzheimer/ -exec /usr/share/fsl/5.0/bin/bet {} {}_brain -f 0.4 -g 0 \;
```

For those who prefer their code spread out over multiple lines:

```
find /home/Desktop/MSc/ImagensMRI/T1/t1inciais/t1alzheimer/ \
    -exec /usr/share/fsl/5.0/bin/bet {} {}_brain -f 0.4 -g 0 \;
```

#### Example

Suppose we have a directory with these files:

```
$ find .
.
./dir1
./dir1/file2
./dir1/file1
```

We can run an `echo` command on each of these files that shows that the file names are substituted correctly into a command:

```
$ find . -exec echo bet {} {}_brain -f 0.4 -g 0 \;
bet . ._brain -f 0.4 -g 0
bet ./dir1 ./dir1_brain -f 0.4 -g 0
bet ./dir1/file2 ./dir1/file2_brain -f 0.4 -g 0
bet ./dir1/file1 ./dir1/file1_brain -f 0.4 -g 0
```

If you only want your command run on regular files, not directories, then add the `-type f` test:

```
$ find . -type f -exec echo bet {} {}_brain -f 0.4 -g 0 \;
bet ./dir1/file2 ./dir1/file2_brain -f 0.4 -g 0
bet ./dir1/file1 ./dir1/file1_brain -f 0.4 -g 0
```

Comment: @GillesQuenot Good catch.  Fixed with `$i` --> `{}`.

Answer (score 0):

Your script should work with the following adjustments:

```
IFS=$'\n' for i in $(find /home/Desktop/MSc/ImagensMRI/T1/t1inciais/t1alzheimer/)
do 
  /usr/share/fsl/5.0/bin/bet "$i" "${i}_brain" -f 0.4 -g 0
done
```

The `$(...)` syntax is for starting `find` as a separate command, instead of creating a string literal `'find ... '`.

The `IFS` is the separator that splits results returned by `find`. We have to update it, because otherwise pieces of filenames with whitespace will be assigned to `i` separately.

This answer here explains [why the `$` in `IFS=$'\n'` is necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4128305/2707792).

Comment: Missing double quotes around all variables. No problem with files with space in her names if well quoting

Comment: @GillesQuenot As I said: one-off script that is supposed to work under the assumption that all file names are benign. The OP used `$i` without quotes, therefore I assume that the files are named something like `mriscan00001.png` to `mriscan12345.png`. But yes, you are right, it's very brittle. Veeery brittle.

Comment: Not a good reason to not quote them every times (apart for int values)

Comment: @GillesQuenot This should be slightly better, I hope? Or will the IFS do something funny?

Comment: Yes, better now. No need IFS

Comment: @GillesQuenot it didn't work without the IFS part if the names had spaces in them, it used every space-separated piece of filename as `i`. I can't say right away what the `$` after the IFS is good for, if I remember correctly it had something to do with `'\\n'` behaving strangely otherwise. Searching some doc about this... Thanks for constructive feedback ;)