# How to use each line of a file as an argument to a for loop

Tags: bash, for-loop

I'm hoping to do a command on each line listed within foo.txt, where each line of foo.txt is a file name.

There's been plenty of great support for this question, and have tried a [while read](https://superuser.com/questions/233675/process-each-line-of-a-file-in-bash), [another while read](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149726/how-to-parse-each-line-of-a-text-file-as-an-argument-to-a-command), I am now trying to do a [for loop](https://linuxhint.com/bash_for_each_line/). However, I'm starting to think the issue is in the body of the loop.

```
#!/bin/bash
File=/mnt/d/R_projects/EC/foo.txt
Lines=$(cat $File)
for Line in $Lines
do
    echo  "fastp -i /mnt/d/R_projects/EC/download/fastq/$Line -o /mnt/e/EC/fastp_trimmed/$Line"
   ./fastp -i /mnt/d/R_projects/EC/download/fastq/$Line -o /mnt/e/EC/fastp_trimmed/$Line
done
```

I unfortunately receive the error:
ERROR: Failed to open file: /mnt/d/R_projects/EC/download/fastq/SRR6132950_1.fastq

The file exists, and doing `less` confirms.
Oddly, the echo doesn't echo what I was expecting and instead states:
" -o /mnt/e/EC/fastp_trimmed/SRR6132950_1.fastqRR6132950_1.fastq"

What could be causing this issue? It's as if the first half was cut off.

Comment: See: [Looping through the content of a file in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1521462/3776858)

Comment: `Lines=$(cat $File)` is a *UUOc* (*Unnecessary Use Of* `cat`). Redirection is the proper approach. Before you can redirect a line and read it in a for-loop line-by-line, you need to set `IFS` to `'\n'`. Then you can do `for i in $(< somefile); do ...`

Comment: **Your file probably has carriage returns** (i.e. CRLF instead of LF) because you copied, accessed or editted it from Windows. Remove them; there are hundreds of existing Qs on this.

Comment: The canonical question about DOS/Windows files (with CRLF line endings) is: [Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings) You can also trim CRs in a `while read` loop (in bash, but not all other shells), with `while IFS=$'\r' read Line; do ... done <"$File"`

Comment: In case you're dealing with carriage return characters, I hope you know you can use the `dos2unix` command? :-)

Answer (score -1):

Thank you all,

I had suspected the windows \r\n was causing an issue here, but I tried in nano to delete these and moved on. Notepad++ showed my error and was able to fix with notepad++ edit>EOL conversion>Linux (LF).

I also adapted the suggestions to remove cat and add IFS - the [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128235/what-is-the-exact-meaning-of-ifs-n/66942306#66942306) was helpful.

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=$'\n'
for Line in $(< /mnt/d/R_projects/EC/foo.txt); do
    echo  "$Line"
    echo  "fastp -i /mnt/d/R_projects/EC/download/fastq/$Line -o /mnt/e/EC/fastp_trimmed/$Line"
   ./fastp -i /mnt/d/R_projects/EC/download/fastq/$Line -o /mnt/e/EC/fastp_trimmed/$Line
done
```

I have like a million needs for running commands based on a text file and this will be extremely helpful for further applications.

Comment: This still won't work if any of the lines could be interpreted as a glob, as the unquoted command substitution will undergo filename expansion as well as word-splitting. [Use a while loop](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).