# How to preserve newline characters in grep result?

Tags: bash

I want to assign the grep result to a variable for further use:

```
lines=$(cat abc.txt | grep "hello")
```

but seems newline characters are removed in the result,  when I do

```
echo $lines
```

only one line is printed. How can I preserve newline characters, so when I echo $lines, it generates the same result as `cat abc.txt | grep "hello"` does.

Comment: Feline abuse: `lines=$(grep hello abc.txt)`.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613572/capturing-multiple-line-output-to-a-bash-variable/

Comment: I think you'd want `lines="$(grep hello abc.txt)"`

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You want to say

```
echo "$lines"
```

instead of

```
echo $lines
```

To elaborate:

`echo $lines` means "Form a new command by replacing `$lines` with the contents of the variable named `lines`, splitting it up on whitespace to form zero or more new arguments to the `echo` command.  For example:

```
lines='1 2 3'
echo $lines   # equivalent to "echo 1 2 3"
lines='1   2   3'
echo $lines   # also equivalent to "echo 1 2 3"
lines="1
2
3"
echo $lines   # also equivalent to "echo 1 2 3"
```

All these examples are equivalent, because the shell ignores the specific kind of whitespace between the individual words stored in the variable `lines`.  Actually, to be more precise, the shell splits the contents of the variable on the characters of the special `IFS` (Internal Field Separator) variable, which defaults (at least on my version of bash) to the three characters space, tab, and newline.

`echo "$lines"`, on the other hand, means to form a single new argument from the exact value of the variable `lines`.

For more details, see the "Expansion" and "Word Splitting" sections of the bash manual page.

Answer (score 2):

Using the Windows port for grep (not the original question, I kow and not applicable to *nix).   I found that `-U` solved the problem nicely.

From the `--help`:

> -U, --binary do not strip CR characters at EOL (MSDOS)

Comment: It works. Thanks @Haggisbreath.  using -U logs getting printed with new line. grep command is... 
electron app.js | grep --line-buffered -i -e "error" -U | tee logs.txt