# Newline characters don't get printed

Tags: bash

I'm writing a bash script that first saves a text (with newline characters coming from `grep`), and then prints it later. For some reason, the line `echo $TEXT` prints just a single line. I took a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5386562/824644), and I believe I'm using the same thing (but with $() instead of backticks), but it's not working. Any ideas?

```
TEXT=$(grep Vacation vacations | grep Day)
echo "Counting days based on the following:"
echo "###############################################################"
echo $TEXT
echo "###############################################################"
```

Comment: Could you add a sample file so we can try it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to quote `$TEXT`, or else the newlines are treated like any other whitespace and simply serve as word boundaries when determining the arguments to `echo`.

```
echo "$TEXT"
```

However, it would be more efficient to simply run `grep` once you've already printed the header.

```
echo "Counting ..."
echo "####..."
grep Vacation vacations | grep Day
echo "####..."
```

Comment: Doh, I read the other answer backward... Thanks! It works :) Any idea how to maintain `grep` highlighting when it's printed?

Comment: @PedroGordo, that's a matter of `grep` detecting that output isn't to a TTY and disabling color highlighting. Read the manual for your version of grep; it may support something like `--color=always` (vs `--color=auto` depending on TTY detection for the toggle).