# No line breaks with "cat"

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, echo

This code should read from `wget2.html` and output the links found. But it gives me output without line breaks.
How can I force cat to add line breaks?

```
chksitename=$(cat wget2.html | grep -e "$sitename" | sed -e "s/^.*\("$sitename".*jpg\).*$/\1/g" | sort | uniq)
echo $chksitename
```

Comment: Where exactly would you like the linebreaks to be added?

Comment: [UUoC](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#cat), but what are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: BTW, don't do `cat myfile | grep pattern`. Do `grep pattern myfile` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
echo $chksitename | tr ' ' '\n'
```

Comment: That's a very funny way to do it; it works, no doubt, but not orthodox.

Comment: I found this looking to set collapsed JSON to an env var, and I liked this method. My usage: `export TEST=$(cat test.json | tr -d '\n'| tr -d ' ')`

Answer (score 16):

The problem is not in the `cat` line but in the `echo` line.  To get the line breaks, you need to use:

```
echo "$chksitename"
```

See also [Capturing Multiple Line Output to a Bash Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613572/capturing-multiple-line-output-to-a-bash-variable/613580#613580).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

I think you can replace your `cat/grep/sed` with one `sed`:

```
sed -e -n "/$sitename/ s@^.*\("$sitename".*jpg\).*$@\1@pg" wget.html
```

And you can replace `sort | uniq` to `sort -u`.