# Why is awk not printing out newlines?

Tags: awk

I have a file which looks like this:

```
1 
2
AA 
4
5
AA BB
7
8
AA BB CC
10
11
AA BB CC DD
```

I am using **awk** to extract only every `nth` line where `n=3`.

```
>>awk 'NR%3==0' /input/file_foo >> output/file_foobar
```

The output is appearing in a single line as:

```
AA AA BB AA BB CC AA BB CC DD
```

.....and so on

I want it to appear as:

```
AA 
AA BB 
AA BB CC 
AA BB CC DD
```

I tried using `\n`, `printf` with `\n`, and so on but it doesn't work as I expect. Please advise.

Comment: Which shell are you using?  That's an aconventional prompt which doesn't indicate the shell type.  How are you demonstrating that the data is flat on a single line?

Comment: Did you try changing the RS variable?

Comment: Thanks. I was using Cygwin but the line terminator was not proper as Shiplu mentioned.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A verbose way,

```
awk '{ if (NR%3==0) { print $0}  }'
```

Also you can use `{printf("%s\n\n", $0)}` too. if single `\n` does not work.

If it still does not work you might need to check the line terminator. It may not be proper. Use the `RS` variable in `awk` to separate on the unusual line terminator.

Comment: Does not seem to work at all. The second one produces some errors. the first one does not print the correct results at all.                       I actually want to copy every 3rd line in a file to another file, that's all.

Comment: I think your Files line terminator is not proper.

Comment: Thanks Shiplu. The line terminator was not proper. It works now.

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is in the way you're showing the data, not in the processing.

```
$ cat x
1 
2
AA 
4
5
AA BB
7
8
AA BB CC
10
11
AA BB CC DD
$ awk 'NR%3==0' x
AA 
AA BB
AA BB CC
AA BB CC DD
$
```

I suspect that what you're doing is similar to:

```
$ awk 'NR%3==0' x > y
$ x=$(<y)
$ echo $x
AA AA BB AA BB CC AA BB CC DD
$ echo "$x"
AA 
AA BB
AA BB CC
AA BB CC DD
$
```

This would confuse you.  See also: [Capturing multi-line output to a bash variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613572/capturing-multiple-line-output-to-a-bash-variable/613580#613580).

Answer (score 2):

Use the following with `print` for each line:

```
awk 'NR%3==0 { print $0 }' /input/file_foo >> output/file_foobar
```