# Why are the empty (^$) lines not present in this variable?

Tags: bash, sed

```
$ cat temp.txt
hello, world!





$ cat temp.txt | sed -n '1,4p'
hello, world!



$ ret=$(cat temp.txt | sed -n '1,4p')
$ echo "$ret"
hello, world!
$
```

I am wondering why the $ret variable does not have the empty lines.

Much appreciated for the help.

Comment: "$() - Strips trailing newlines."

http://stackoverflow.com/a/5322980/399077

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the bash man page (emphasis mine):

> Bash performs the expansion by executing command and replacing the command substitution with  > the  standard output of the command, **with any trailing newlines
>   deleted**.  Embedded newlines are not deleted, but they may be removed during word
>   splitting.   The command substitution $(cat file) can be replaced by the equivalent but 
>   faster $(< file).

Answer (score -1):

The parsing of the `echo "$ret"` skips whitespace in determining what the actual arguments to `echo` will be. Play around with things like this to understand better:

```
x=$(echo '   foo    ')
echo "x${x}x"
echo ${x}
echo "${x}"
```

Comment: He is quoting `$ret`, though. The question is, why aren't the blank lines in `$ret`?