# Use return value of a shell command as a value in shell script?

Tags: linux, shell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Capturing multiple line output to a bash variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613572/capturing-multiple-line-output-to-a-bash-variable)

For example I want to run ls command and take the return list as a value kept in a array in shell script.

Something like

run

```
#ls
fileA
fileB
fileC
```

kept this return list in a variable that keeps a array

```
variable A = ["fileA","fileB","fileC"];
```

I cannot give the exact notation for code since I do not know how to write shell script. After I learn this, I 'll.

Comment: I think the bit about Arrays is the key differentiating factor from most possible duplicates. Interesting question, don't close it.

Answer (score 7):

```
#!/bin/bash
variableA=$(ls)
echo $variableA
```

That should be your shell script assuming that you have `bash`

Then all you'd need to do is `chmod +x shell_script` to make it executable.

If you use `ls > contents.file` the result of `ls` is saved to a file called `contents.file`.
Remember, `>` rewrites the entire file while `>>` appends to the last line.

Comment: can I get a array of the values

Comment: I am not the best bash guy. So what I do is generally populate files and then read from them again. As for arrays, you'd want to see [this](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/store-multi-line-output-into-an-array-in-a-linux-bash-script-706878/#post3454704) And let us know how it goes!

Answer (score 3):

```
variableA=$(ls)
echo "$variableA"
```