# What does single parenthesis do here?

Tags: bash, shell

I encountered this code:

```
file=$(<filename)
```

This reads the file from the filename.

My question is how does this work?

I read from this post:

[How to use double or single brackets, parentheses, curly braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188199/bash-double-or-single-bracket-parentheses-curly-braces)

It tells me, single parentheses can function as:

```
- Sub bash execution
- Array construction
```

But in the case above, I do not know how this explains.

Besides this question, I want to know that why when I do `echo $file`, the file content concatenate into one line?

Comment: Your second question is addressed in [Capturing multiple-line output to a `bash` variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613572/capturing-multiple-line-output-to-a-bash-variable/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$(...)` performs **command substitution**; the command inside is read and the output from stdout is returned to the script.

`<...` is **redirection**; the contents of the file are read and fed into stdin of the process.

Putting the two together results in an implicit `cat`, connecting the stdin of the redirection to the stdout of the command substitution, reading the contents of the file into the script.

Comment: One advantage of `$(<file)` over `$(cat file)` is that `bash` does not actually invoke an external process for `$(<file)`, so it is likely to be faster (no `exec()`, and almost certainly no `fork()` either).

Comment: Why do we need command substitution for redirecting input? I tried `file=<filename` and it is not working (but no errors either). How does this happen?

Comment: @texasbruce: Urgh!  The notation `file=<filename` is a very odd construct.  It is equivalent to `file='' <filename`; it exports the environment variable `file` with an empty value, redirects standard input from `filename` and runs nothing.  It is a degenerate notation that has very limited use (it would identify that `filename` is missing, but that's about all), but it isn't formally an error.  The `$(<file)` notation is essentially a `bash` optimization for the common `$(cat file)` notation. There are some caveats (aliases and functions, for example), which is why I said 'essentially'.

Comment: Note that `$(<file)` is a bashism (not POSIX) and thus won't work on some other Bourne heritage shells. The safe bet is to actually use `$(cat file)`, or better yet, if script logic permits, redirect file into whatever command consumes its contents.

Comment: @Jens Not POSIX indeed but not really a bashism as `$(<file)` was already present in ksh88 in 1988 and borrowed by bash-2.02 in 1998, ten years later.

Answer (score 2):

You must surround your variable into double quotes, else it will be expanded into command line arguments that will be passed to echo.

If you surround it into double quotes variable will be passed as single argument and echo will display it correctly.

```
echo "$file"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $file
```

will give you a concatenated output.

Try

```
echo "$file"
```

this will give you an output in multiple lines.