# How to convert a file of spaces and special characters into an indexed string in bash?

Tags: bash

I have a file *consC* that is a line of spaces and *'s that looks like this:

```
                                          **** **     *
```

How do I read into a string that keeps the location of *'s intact without losing the spaces and then get the index of the *'s

Answer (score 2):

```
echo '          **  **   *****    *     ' > consC.txt
consC="$(cat consC.txt)"
echo "$consC"
```

**Edit:** One of the comments mentions that the second line can be simplified:

```
consC=$(< consC.txt)
```

- No need to use `cat` as `<` will do the job,
- and double-quotes not needed when using `$(...)` construct in an assignment

Although double-quotes are definitely needed in line 3: `echo`.

Comment: Or, in `bash`, you can avoid the `cat` command by using `consC=$(< consC.txt)`.  The double quotes aren't necessary in the `$(...)` notation (either variant); and the `<` notation reads named file without invoking `cat`.  The double quotes are very necessary around the variable in the `echo` command — see also [Capturing ulti-line output to a `bash` variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613572/capturing-multiple-line-output-to-a-bash-variable/). Using the `read` command strips leading and trailing blanks.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Thanks for those hints. I wasn't aware that `cat` could be replaced by `<` in this situation.  I generally always like to use double-quotes "just in case" as I tend to forget the rules about when they are or aren't necessary.

Comment: I use double quotes quite a lot too — again, better safe than sorry.

Comment: however when I try to use the same string to return the first location of the * character I am having trouble. I tried the usual:         echo `expr "$consC" "*"`                                                 but that gave me     expr:syntax error. Is there an awk version of the command that I can use. I need the indices of the *'s in the consC string.

Answer (score 1):

You can also set the input field separator:

```
while IFS= read line; do
    echo "$line"
done < input
```

Comment: For a general solution, you want `read -r`, as plain `read` will interpret e.g. backslashes, not read them literally.