# Shell script variable not storing content of file

Tags: shell, variables

I am trying to store the content of a text file in one variable and using that variable as body in email sending. Below is the code to store the value in variable

```
ct=`cat a.txt`
```

I tried with

```
ct="`cat a.txt`"
```

The issue is, when I am executing the script as *sh script.sh*. The whole contents of *a.txt* are getting stored in variable *ct*.

But when I am executing the script without the *sh* extension (i.e. *script.ksh*). Only few contents are storing is variable *ct*. I am not able to trace what the issue is.
Need your help.

Comment: `ct=$(<a.txt)` will do it.  Make sure you quote `"$ct"` when you use it as the body for the mail or you will lose formatting. Also, you can simple do `cat a.txt | mail -s "some subject" email@someaddress` if you are using `mail/mailx`

Comment: Thanks for your response David. I tried with same option but same result. I am passing this variable to another script which is used to send email

Comment: This issue is coming only when I am executing the script as "script.ksh" and "./script.ksh". This is working fine when script is executed as "sh script.ksh". Is there any environmental file change required

Comment: What is the **top line** in your script? `#!/bin/sh`? You have made your script executable right? `chmod 0755 script.ksh` ? If so `./script.ksh` should work.

Comment: Does your script have a "shebang line" (something starting with `#!`) ? If yes, check that line. If no, see what shell you are currently running with `ps`. You can also try to run the script is sh by giving `sh` as one command, execute `./script.ksh` and give `exit` to come back to your normal shell.

Comment: Yes, "shebang line" is there #!/bin/ksh. And script has executable rights also. But still same output.

Comment: Does [Capturing multiple line output to a Bash variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613572/) help?  If not, show your code that is using `$ct`.

Comment: Can you change `#!/bin/ksh` into `#!/bin/sh` ? Perhaps the sh really is bash, and can do more. You said `sh script.ksh` works, and that way the interpreter on the first line is ignored. I bet the `ksh script.ksh` fails.

Comment: You can also try to make a small testscript like `set -vx; ct=$(<a.txt); echo  "$ct"` and post the results in an edit of your question.

Comment: Yes, I changed the shebang line #!/bin/ksh into #!/bin/sh . It's working fine. In Unix #!/bin/ksh works fine, but in CentOS it was giving this problem. Is there any major change in behaviour of korn shell in Unix and Linux ?

Comment: Most things work the same for Linux ksh, when installed. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

On default Linux systems the /bin/ksh is not installed. Sometimes you can install a ksh package. The work-around `ln -s /bin/bash /bin/ksh` is dangereous, since bash is a superset most of the times, but is not always compatible.

For the CentOS environment the best way would be shanging the shebang line to `#!/bin/bash`, but be aware of the following issues:

- Version control
  When you want to use the same scripts on CentOS and other Unix OS, you need to maintain two versions or get bash installed on the other Unix OS.
- Developers should write in one language, bash or ksh
  When you need to maintain large ksh scripts, writing new scripts in bash will become confusing.
- Check/test your code
  Do you set variables inside while-loops? They can get lost!