# Take care of last newline while capturing commands output

Tags: bash

I know `$(cmd)` captures the output of `cmd` into a string. However, it doesn't take care of the newline characters at the end.

Here's a demonstration:

```
a=$(echo x)
b=$(echo -n x)
[ "$a" = "$b" ] && echo equal
```

`a` and `b` capture outputs differed by a `"\n"` but these variables have the same value.

So my goal is still to capture the output of a command, but this time I want to preserve the last newline character(s) if there are any.

Comment: Would you please elaborate why you want to preserve the trailing newlines? Depends on your use case, maybe there is a simple workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Trailing newlines are removed

POSIX requires that the `$(…)` notation (or the equivalent using back-ticks) strips all trailing newlines from the end of the string that is captured.

> #### [§6.2.3 Command substitution](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03)
>
> …, removing sequences of one or more `<newline>` characters at the end of the substitution.

There isn't a simple way around that, or to detect how many newlines were deleted.

#### Add a single newline to the end of the output

If you have Bash 4.x (4.3 tested) you can play with [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) and the substring notation, and add a dummy line of output to the end of the original string (that's the `echo n` in this example):

```
$ x=$(echo pandemonium; blanklines 4; echo n)
$ echo "$x"
pandemonium




n
$ y=${x: 0: -1}
$ echo "$y"
pandemonium




$
```

When using Bash 3.2 (`GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin16)`) on macOS Sierra, the expansion for `y` generates an error:

```
$ y=${x: 0: -1}
-bash:  -1: substring expression < 0
$
```

See also [Capturing multiple line output to a Bash variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613572/capturing-multiple-line-output-to-a-bash-variable).

#### Reliable and POSIX-compliant

Or you can use a simpler, more portable ([POSIX-compatible](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02)) substitution suggested by the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5322980/) — as applied to this answer:

```
$ y=${x%n}
$ echo "$y"
pandemonium




$
```

Given that this works in strict POSIX shells and both Bash 3.x and 4.x, there's no need for the substring variant.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the link. I got the answer I want at http://stackoverflow.com/a/5322980/1232832, good that it's more portable.