# Shell: use grep on a variable with newlines

Tags: linux, shell, grep, busybox

I want to parse each line from a text with this structure:

```
  ipv4address: 1.2.3.4/29
  ipv4gateway: 1.2.3.1
  ipv4mtu: 1500
  ipv4dnsserver: 8.8.8.8
  ipv4dnsserver: 8.8.4.4
```

Newlines are seperated by `\n`.

To generate this file I use a program which will output some information:

```
CONFIG=$(umbim $DBG -d $device -n -t $tid config) || {
        echo "mbim[$$]" "config failed"
        return 1
    }
```

then I write out the $CONFIG variable to a file, just to reread it again, which seems wrong to me.

```
echo "$CONFIG" > /tmp/ip
```

Then after that I use `grep` to get the information:

```
IP=$(grep "ipv4address" /tmp/ip |grep -E -o "(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)")
NM=$(grep "ipv4address" /tmp/ip |grep -o '.\{2\}$')
GW=$(grep "ipv4gateway" /tmp/ip |grep -E -o "(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)")
```

I want to avoid writing to a file. It would be better, or at least it seems better if I could grep on the $CONFIG variable. But using `echo $CONFIG` will not yield the results as newlines are ommitted with this. The same with `printf`.

I am using busybox if that helps.

```
BusyBox v1.25.1 () built-in shell (ash)
```

Edit: This is what happens when I want to print out the variable with `echo`:

```
$ CONFIG=$(cat /tmp/ip)
$ echo -e $CONFIG
ipv4address: 1.2.3.4/29 ipv4gateway: 1.2.3.1 ipv4mtu: 1500 ipv4dnsserver: 8.8.8.8 ipv4dnsserver: 8.8.4.4
```

Comment: `echo -e` will also output new lines.

Comment: Thanks, I added an example some seconds ago. Unsuccessfull unfortunateley.

Comment: Without dealing with `grep | grep`, you can use: `IP=$(echo "$CONFIG" | grep "ipv4address" | grep -E …)` etc.  Note the double quotes around `"$CONFIG"`. You may not be able to use Bash 'here strings' since you're using BusyBox, but they would save a process if available.  I'd look at using `sed` rather than `grep | grep`.  Note [Capturing multi-line output to a bash variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613572/).

Comment: A quick and dirty `sed` could be added (eg. `echo -e "$CONFIG" | sed $'s/ ip/\\\nip/g'`)

Comment: to the downvoter: why the downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shell variable should almost always be quoted. If instead of `echo $CONFIG | grep ...` you use `echo "$CONFIG" | grep ...`, the newlines will be preserved and you'll get the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Why won't you just use something like this?

```
eval $(umbim $DBG -d $device -n -t $tid config | tr -d ' ' | grep ^ipv4 | tr a-z: A-Z=)
IP=${IPV4ADDRESS%/*}
NM=${IPV4ADDRESS##*/}
GW=$IPV4GATEWAY
```