# get docker images command's output with bash script

Tags: php, bash, shell, docker, quoting

I'm trying to get the `docker images` command output to display it on a webpage.

Ex: [Docker images ouput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baP9M.png)

As you can see on the image, this is well formatted.

But what I get on my web page is one line not formatted at all;

> REPOSITORY TAG IMAGE ID CREATED SIZE nginx latest 3448f27c273f 2 days
>   ago 109.4 MB mysql latest e799c7f9ae9c 3 days ago 407.3 MB

This my script at the moment;

```
docker_images=$(docker images)

echo $docker_images
```

How can I get the well formatted output through my echo ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I tried an `echo nl2br($output)` which gave me this;

[HTML OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsfXK.png)

This is a bit better but still not well formatted. Any ideas how to improve this ?

Edit :

This is working now, i'm getting the output that I want. I juste had to do this;

```
echo "<pre>";
echo nl2br($output) or $output;
echo "</pre>";
```

Well it is in plain text. If anyone want to manipulate these, you can use the docker API. https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.24/

Answer (score 1):

This is related to how shell treats newlines, whitespaces, tabs, etc. when printing a variable with and without double-quotes. To get the desired output, please replace

```
echo $docker_images
```

with

```
echo "$docker_images"
```

Please refer [Capturing multiple line output into a Bash variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613572/capturing-multiple-line-output-into-a-bash-variable) for a much more detailed explanation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You're right this will work in shell, but this isn't working with php I still get it echo'ed in one line.