# Replace space with newline except space wrapped by special characters

Tags: linux, bash, shell

In shell, I have a variable storing private key, but every newline character in original private key is replaced with a space now, so the variable looks like:

```
PK="-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- aaa bbb ccc ... zzz -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"
```

Now I need to redirect the string to a file, and I need to replace space with newline character. But if I simply run `echo $PK | tr " " "\n" > key`, spaces in `BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY` and `END RSA PRIVATE KEY` will also be replaced with newline, so I get a strange file looks like:

```
-----BEGIN
RSA
PRIVATE
KEY-----
aaa
bbb
ccc
...
zzz
-----END
RSA
PRIVATE
KEY-----
```

So my question is how to replace space with newline in the key body and keep space inside  `-----` unchanged. What I expect to get is:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
aaa
bbb
ccc
...
zzz
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: There are no spaces in a RSA key's body...?!? All you need is a newline after `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` and before `-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`.

Comment: @DevSolar Thanks. And how can I add a newline after `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` and before `-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`...?

Comment: maybe you get space because you forgot to double quote variables as command argument like  in `echo $PK | tr " " "\n" > key`; must be `echo "$PK"`, other issues you may encounter is globbing. `PK="a * b";` compare `echo $PK` and `echo "$PK"`

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul Yes, you are right, I don't know the difference between `echo "$PK"` and `echo $PK` before, sorry for that...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While this is not the *exact* answer you're looking for, I think this is what you're *really* trying to do:

To capture the private key in a variable, do so:

```
PK="$(cat ~/.id_rsa)" # or whatever command you're getting the key from
```

Then, to dump it into a file:

```
echo "$PK" > key # notice the additional quotes
```

The additional quotes when `echo`ing back the variable preserve the newlines captured in the input. No `sed`/`awk`/`tr` magic required.

reference: [Capturing multiple line output into a Bash variable](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/a/613580/1220089)

Comment: Thanks! But the variable is produced by another application, I can only access this variable, and I can do nothing with the original private key...

Comment: If the other application is doing it's job correctly, all you have to do is `echo "$PK"` instead of `echo $PK` and it should work. You don't need to get the original key itself, the `cat` is just as an example.

Comment: @norshteintooma: And if the other application is *not* doing its job correctly, send a bug report. ;-) Anyway, the *variable* is created by another application? How does *that* work? Are you sure the PK is not actually the *output* of another application (like ffledgling showcased with `cat` here)?

Comment: @DevSolar In fact, I'm using concourse, and I provide the private key string via a config file, then concourse will export string as an environment variable inside the container, and I do my jobs inside the container.

Comment: @norshteintooma: Ah, *environment* variables. I was stuck for a moment trying to imagine how another application would magically "inject" a variable into your script. ;-) Nevermind. Good you found your (simple) solution.

Answer (score 8):

Using `gnu-awk`, you can do this:

```
awk -v RS='-+(BEGIN|END) RSA PRIVATE KEY-+' '{
gsub(/ +/, "\n"); ORS=RT} 1' <<< "$PK"
```

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
aaa
bbb
ccc
...
zzz
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

- Using `-v RS='-+(BEGIN|END) RSA PRIVATE KEY-+'` we set input record separator as `BEGIN` or `END` markers.
- Using `gsub` we replace all spaces with newlines in the main body
- Using `ORS=RT` we put header and footer back in output.

---

Alternative `gnu sed` solution:

```
sed -E 's/(-+(BEGIN|END) RSA PRIVATE KEY-+) *| +/\1\n/g' <<< "$PK"
```

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
aaa
bbb
ccc
...
zzz
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: Could you explain the sed regex and substitution?

The regex `(-+(BEGIN|END) RSA PRIVATE KEY-+) *| +`, will match (and group) the strings `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----` or `-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY----` (with one or more leading or trailing hyphens), and any number of spaces after (` *`) or it will match one or more spaces (` +`). In the replacement part (`\1\n`), the first group (`\1`) will kept as such (retaining the BEGIN/END tags), and the `\n` is the actual replacement for all the spaces matched by the ` +` in the match regex I guess?

Comment: Indeed, you have understood and explained it really well.