# How To Saving Zenity List Output With Its Separator?

Tags: bash, debian, zenity

I have a simple list window in [zenity](https://help.gnome.org/users/zenity/3.24/) with some options to choose in a simple shell scripting as showing below :

```
#!/bin/bash
VAR=$(zenity --list --multiple --separator="\n" --column="col.1"  --column="col.2" FALSE "option 1" FALSE "option 2" FALSE "option3" --checklist)
echo $VAR >> output
```

and when i choose a multiple options, the output file contents is:

```
option 1 option 2
```

so, how can i save the output of the resulting script with the `\n` separator like this:

```
option 1 
option 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with echo -e :

```
echo -e "$VAR" >> output
```

Answer (score 1):

For better explanation of how double quotes on bash variable is parsed see the link to earlier responses on similar subject

[Capturing multiple line output into a Bash variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613572/capturing-multiple-line-output-into-a-bash-variable)