# Displays the calendar list for the year 2000

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I trying to display the current years and the calendar of 2000s
but I run the script it alone display the calendar of 2000s. I want both to be display. need some help

```
clear
#!/bin/bash
echo This is the current year.
Year="date '+%Y'"
$Year
echo This is the time:
date "+%r"
Date='cal 2000'
echo  This is the calendar list for the year 2000
$Date
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

#### Initial answer

The shebang must be the first line to be useful; otherwise, it's just an odd-ball comment.

You should simply run `cal` (with its output going to the terminal — standard output) rather than capturing the output of the command in a variable which you then try to execute.

Your script contains the lines:

```
Date='cal 2000'
echo  This is the calendar list for the year 2000
$Date
```

The last line tries to execute a program `2000` with 462 arguments.  To make that work vaguely sanely, you'd need:

```
Date='cal 2000'
echo "This is the calendar list for the year 2000"
echo "$Date"
```

The double quotes are crucial to getting a well-formatted output for the value in `$date`.  See also [Capturing multiple line output into a Bash variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/613580/15168).

This should do the job as I understand it:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
echo "This is the current year."
Year="$(date '+%Y')"
cal $Year
echo "This is the time:"
date '+%r'
echo "This is the calendar for the year 2000"
cal 2000
```

#### From the comments

> I don't need the calendar for year 2020. All I need is the four-digit number of 2020 but I still need the calendar for year 2000.

Oh!  Well, that requires some trivial changes to the code above:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
echo "This is the current year: $(date '+%Y')"
echo "This is the time: $(date '+%r')"
echo "This is the calendar for the year 2000"
cal 2000
```

Or, if you want the values on a separate line from the descriptions:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
echo "This is the current year"
date '+%Y'
echo "This is the time"
date '+%r'
echo "This is the calendar for the year 2000"
cal 2000
```

There are endless possible variations on this — the choice is yours.  Why the year 2000 is so important is mysterious to the outsider, but it is easily managed, as shown.

Comment: The results is still the same. it only display the cal 2000 only.

Comment: I don't see how that's possible if you copy'n'paste the code in the answer.  Copy it to `cal89.sh` (or any other filename that doesn't exist).  Run `bash cal89.sh` — you should have both 2020 and 2000 calendars scroll past.  Rerun with `bash cal89.sh | less` to try again with the output shown a screen page at a time.  You could use `bash -x cal89.sh` to see what's going on — the commands that are executed as they are executed.  If you had a function called `cal` that did something weird that was created in your `.bashrc` file, or something like that, then all bets are off.

Comment: I have a front-end script for `cal` also called `cal` — it maps names to numbers, basically.  It starts off by trying to locate the executable.  That code is: `CAL="";
for cal in /bin/cal /usr/bin/cal /usr/local/bin/cal; do [ -x $cal ] && CAL=$cal && break; done; [ -z "$CAL" ] && { echo "Cannot find cal in /bin or /usr/bin" 1>&2; exit 1; }` (with semicolons added so that it should work even if you copy'n'paste from the comment where newlines are removed — the original is spread over 6 lines. It ends up running `exec $CAL $month $year`. You could add the finding code into the script.

Comment: I don't need the calendar for year 2020. all I need is the four digit numbers  of 2020 but I still need the calendar for year 2000.