# BASH:Why is printf to a var removing spaces?

Tags: bash

Why is the output of these two different? I want the spaces to be preserved.

```
#!/bin/bash

x="foo"
printf "%-12s *" $x

echo " "

y=$(printf "%-12s" $x)
echo $y "*"
```

Running it gives

```
foo          *
foo *
```

I want the second line to look like the first.

Comment: `printf` does preserve the spaces -- its the `echo` that's removing them (when unquoted). Try `echo "$y *"` instead.

Comment: Very closely related to [Capturing multiple line output into a Bash variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/613580/15168) — the basic answer is "quote variables used in argument lists" (almost always — absolutely always if the spacing matters).

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to quote the `$y`:

```sh
echo "${y} *"
```

```
#!/bin/bash

x="foo"
printf "%-12s *" $x

echo " "

y=$(printf "%-12s" $x)
echo "$y" "*"
```

```
➜ ./test.sh
foo          *
foo          *
➜
```

[More information about when to use double quotes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary)

Answer (score 0):

Ypu can use `printf` too

```
printf '%s *\n' "$y"
```

Comment: You can use `printf` again, but the key point is quoting `"$y"`.