# Git status command remote out from bash-Script and email it

Tags: linux, bash, git, shell

Is it possible to do an "git status" and output the result into an echo? Or send the output as email?

I guess the email-thing is no problem but I stuck doing an echo.

What I got

```
clear 
output="$(git status)"
echo output
```

But ... yeah, it won't work and I searched certain examples but they lead always ino a git status if,. and i need the output :( Is there way simple way to get this done

And, how to handle if this should be called on a remote system:

```
ssh ${SSHUSER}@${LIVE_HOST} << EOF
...
EOF
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`echo` is useless](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo); all you need is

```
git status
```

If you genuinely need to store the output in a variable as well as print it, try

```sh
output=$(git status)
echo "$output"
```

To run it remotely, you don't need a here document at all;

```sh
ssh "${SSHUSER}@${LIVE_HOST}" git status
```

and again, if you need to store that in a variable, that would be

```sh
output=$(ssh "${SSHUSER}@${LIVE_HOST}" git status)
echo "$output"
```

If you really want to store the command in a here document, that's possible too:

```sh
ssh "${SSHUSER}@${LIVE_HOST}" <<\:
git status
:
```

or in Bash you could use a "here string":

```sh
ssh "${SSHUSER}@${LIVE_HOST}" <<<'git status'
```

If you want to send the result as email, a common arrangement is

```sh
git status | mail -s "Status report from xyz" you@example.com
```

but [the `mail` command is poorly standardized,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48588035/874188) so you may have to consult a manual page or Google for a bit.

Answer (score 1):

An `echo "$output"` would work better

`echo ouput` would just print `output`.

I just tried:

```sh
$ o=$(git status 2>&1); echo "$o"
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Comment: Ah yes, ok i see my fault. 
So, and If this should happen on a remote server, do I have to set it up like theese?

ssh ${SSHUSER}@${LIVE_HOST} << EOF
git status
EOF

?

Comment: @TheTom only 8f your remote repository is on $HOME, which it shouldn't be. `git -C /path/to/rep status` would work.

Answer (score 0):

It does not working because you missed the variables syntax.

Rewrite your code as follow:

```
clear 
output="$(git status)"
echo "$output"
```

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that

Comment: And, reading from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613572/capturing-multiple-line-output-into-a-bash-variable/613580, you should do `echo "$output"` to get the newlines correctly displayed.

Comment: Clearing the screen as part of your script is doing your users a disservice; I would take that out.