# Cut-n-paste while preserving last blank line for empty match (awk or sed)

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a two-line "**keyword**=**keyvalue**" line pattern (selectively excised from `systemd/networkd.conf` file):

```
DNS=0.0.0.0
DNS=
```

and need the following 2-line answer:

```
0.0.0.0
```

But all attempts using `sed` or `awk` resulted in omitting the newline if the last line pattern matching resulted in an empty match.

EDIT:
Oh, one last thing, this multiline-follow-cut result has to be stored back into a bash variable containing this same 'last blank-line" as well, so this is a two-step operation of preserving last-blank-line

1. multiline prepending-cut-out before (or save content after) the equal `=` symbol while preserving a newline ... in case of an empty result (this is the key here).  Or possibly jerry-rig a weak fixup to attach a new-line in case of an empty match result at the last line.
2. save the multi-line result back into a bash variable

### `sed` Approach

When performing cut up to and include that matched character in bash shell, the `sed` will remove any blank lines having an empty pattern match:

```sh
raw="DNS=0.0.0.0
DNS=
"
rawp="$(printf "%s\n" "$raw")"

kvs="$(echo "$rawp"| sed -e '/^[^=]*=/s///')"

echo "result: '${kvs}'"
```

gives the result:

```
0.0.0.0
```

without the corresponding blank line.

### `awk` Approach

Awk has the same problem:

```sh
raw="DNS=0.0.0.0
DNS=
"
rawp="$(printf "%s\n" "$raw")"

kvs="$(echo "$rawp"| awk -F '=' -v OFS="" '{$1=""; print}')"

echo "result: '${kvs}'"
```

gives the same answer (it removed the blank line).

## Please Advise

Somehow, I need the following answer:

```
0.0.0.0
```

in form of a two-line output containing `0.0.0.0` and a blank line.

### Other Observations Made

I also noticed that if I provided a 3-line data as followed (two with a keyvalue and middle one without a keyvalue:

```
DNS=0.0.0.0
DNS=
DNS=999.999.999.999
```

Both `sed` and `awk` provided the correct answer:

```
0.0.0.0

999.999.999.999
```

Weird, uh?

The above regex (both `sed` and `awk`) works for:

- a one-line with its keyvalue,
- any-line provided that any lines have its non-empty keyvalue, BUT
- last line MUST have a keyvalue.

Just doesn't work when the last-line has an empty keyvalue.

:-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `awk`:

```sh
raw="DNS=0.0.0.0
DNS=
"

awk -F= 'NF == 2 {print $2}' <<< "$raw"
0.0.0.0
```

Following `cut` should also work:

```sh
cut -d= -f2 <<< "${raw%$'\n'}"
0.0.0.0
```

---

To store output including trailing line breaks use `read` with process substitution:

```sh
IFS= read -rd '' kvs < <(awk -F= 'NF == 2 {print $2}' <<< "$raw")

declare -p kvs
declare -- s="0.0.0.0

"
```

[**Code Demo:**](https://ideone.com/IxzGE8)

Comment: Weird.  The answer technically produces two-lines (as checked using the `| wc -l` line-counter pipe.   But I am unable to store that back into a bash variable this said-missing last blank line.  Qualified the question further to state "... and store back into a bash variable."

Comment: ok check my updated answer now

Comment: Testing that now;  Apparently, I've been impacted by a command substitution limitation with regard to last newline via `$(awk ...)`.  I just saw this snippet over at https://stackoverflow.com/a/5322980/4379130   And it is a lot cleaner than delving into `declare/read` complex-combo territory:  `RESULTX="$(./myscript; echo x)"
RESULT="${RESULTX%x}"`  If you agree, I'll accept the answer.  (still testing your original approach).

Comment: Putting a character in the end and removing it is a work around but using `read -d ''` with *process substitution* is proper and standard way of getting it done.

Comment: And ye be absolutely right; not only that, the variable is POSIX-compliant too.

Comment: Can you add a corresponding first step using `grep -E` as a curiosity, if POSIXively possible?

Comment: `grep` is not the right tool for this. `cut` or `awk` will do better job as shown in answer.