# cannot properly store "js-beautify" into bash variable

Tags: bash, js-beautify

I have simple question but it's annoying me ..
who don't know ,`js-beautify` is a library to make ugly stinky js files more readable and beauty ,hence the name ;D

when I do `$ js-beautify somefile.js` in **bash** ,every thing is good and the output is clean as expicted ,but when I try to store that output in a variable `readable=$(js-beautify somefile.js)` then `echo $readable` ,nothing changed !! like I didn't use `js-beautify` at all !!

what's the problem here ?

Comment: Also: Is the command being found? Is it in the $PATH?

Comment: @B.Shea  sorry for the delay (time difference) ... yes the command being found, I installed it via python `pip install js-beautify` and it works fine ,but when i store it in bash variable then `echo` it ,it still ugly **not beautified**

Comment: Now that I understand the question, I took a look. Answer is below :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Echo the variable with double quotes:

`echo "$readable"`

That should give you proper EOLs/newlines. (Also see BASH "[Double Quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html)").

Please note that many blocks of code may not 'expand'/prettify. To test command line output in shell versus online, run it in BASH shell and check it against results here: https://beautifier.io

(It's the same version my pip installed for python/bash use.)

Also see:

[Capturing multiple line output into a Bash variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613572/capturing-multiple-line-output-into-a-bash-variable)

---

PS (to your comment above on question):
To properly install the Python3 `pip` version, the command is actually:
`pip3 install jsbeautifier`  (Or, 'pip'. But, not `js-beautify` - that's the shell command.)

Comment: sheeeeesh thank you so much it works <3 ,how I didn't think about that ! but while that time I sharped my bash skills a bit and did a nasty stuff just to solve it ,and it works also