# AWS Secret manager ssh key read in bash variable

Tags: bash

I am trying to use AWS Secret manager to store a private ssh key and read in bash script.
I created the secret with name testsshkey in Secrets manager.
This is a multiline text stored in SecretsMananger
Then I created the bash script with following

```
secret_key=$(aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --region us-east-1 --secret-id testsshkey --query SecretString --output text)
echo $secret_key
```

When I run this script, it only prints last line of the key

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Capturing multiple line output into a Bash variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613572/capturing-multiple-line-output-into-a-bash-variable)

Comment: `echo "$secret_key"`

Comment: See ["I just assigned a variable, but `echo $variable` shows something else"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else). The key probably also has DOS/Windows line endings, which cause all sorts of confusion in unix tools; see ["Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings)